# Is there a word for the object being cloned?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was talking to a friend about various operations around cloning digital objects and we invented the word clonee for the object being cloned.  Obviously we used the word clone / clones to refer to the new object(s) which were created.  We could not find any usage of clonee in this context nor find the word to describe the object that had been been cloned.  Is there a word for this?

Comment: If it were keys being copied, or papers or photographs, wouldn't it just be the original and the copy?

Comment: I would think that the "Clonee" would enjoy the title of "The Original".